# Mailchimp API 400 and 404 Errors

Tags: perl, mailchimp

I'm using a custom signup form to add users to a Mailchimp list (API v3.0) using Curl. While the process works most of the time, I get occasional 400 errors.

I thought the problem might be related to the binary value returned by the MD5 hash that's appended to the URL string, so I tried using a base 64 hash instead. Using data from a signup that had previously failed, the add was successful.

Later, after several additional successful signups, I received a 404 error, indicating a url path error. When I captured the url, I noticed that the base 64 digest contained a "/" character, which would have terminated that portion of the url string.

When I substituted another (random) alpha character for the "/", the add completed correctly... no error.

(1) I'm not sure why the binary md5 email hash produced occasional errors, and 
(2) If it's ok to use a regex to substitute another alpha character for the occasional "/". Seems like a potentially problematic hack.

This now seems to be working (no errors, good adds), but I'm concerned about the modified base 64 hash, that is no longer a real hash of the email address:

```
my $digest = md5_base64(lc($email));
$digest =~ s/\//x/;

    my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

my $url = "$endpoint/$listid/members/" . $digest;
```

Since using this modified version of Mailchimp API code that has been posted elsewhere, all adds through the signup form have worked correctly.

Comment: I don't see a question in here.

Comment: The question is: will this hack break something on the Mailchimp side?